# How to swap data for a single column in table?

Tags: sql

Consider there is a table
Employee with attribute EmployeeID, ExperienceLevel
Now the ExperienceLevel can be Junior or Senior. I want to switch the value of the rows which have junior with senior and senior with junior. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE Employee 
  SET ExperienceLevel = 
  CASE ExperienceLevel 
     WHEN 'Junior' THEN 'Senior'
     WHEN 'Senior' THEN 'Junior'
     ELSE Experiencelevel
  END
```

Comment: May want to add `ELSE Experiencelevel`, otherwise non-`Junior` or -`Senior` values will be set to `NULL`

Comment: Thanks alot. One more thing I want to ask that can I delete data from multiple tables like this "delete from table1, table2, table3"

Comment: @AnkurBansal - no, update/delete/insert only work with one table at a time, period.

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee set ExperienceLevel =
(case ExperienceLevel
   when 'Junior' then 'Senior'
   else 'Junior'
 end);
```

Depending on which RDBMS you're using, you might have to tweak the syntax a bit.